# Find with regex not working on CentOS 7

Tags: centos, find, regular-expressions

I have problem with find and regular expression. I would like to find files in /etc, which name begin of a or b. I tried this commands:

```
find /etc -type f -regex '^a'
find /etc -regextype sed -regex "^a"
find /etc -regextype egrep -regex '^a'
find /etc -regextype posix-egrep -regex '^a'
```

But not working. I have 20 files in /etc which name begin of a, but my regexp not find this files. What i do wrong?

Regards Paweł

Comment: Probably relevant: https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#index-_002dregex

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`-regex` matches the complete path, not the filename only.

The closest thing I came up with would be:

```
find /etc -type f  -regex '.+/[ab][^/]+'
```

This matches a `/`, followed by `a` or `b`, followed by everything which is not another `/`.

Answer (score 1):

This used to be very simple, with:

```
find /etc -type f -name 'a*'
```